# Сериализация: как сохранить лист объектов своего класса в файл?

Tags: c#, settings, list, сериализация

Точнее говоря, вопрос в том, как сделать это:

- Быстро;
- Несколькими удобными строчками кода;
- Туда и обратно, т.е. сохранять и загружать при запуске приложения;

Желательно сохранять всё это в `settings` (короче говоря, объекты из листов будут потом загружаться в контролы, редактироваться из них, и после сохраняться). Проблема только лишь в том, как их быстро и правильно сохранить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я делал сериализацию в Xml так:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name {get; set;} // Это будет элементом

    [XmlAttribute("Value")]   
    public string Value {get; set;} // Это будет атрибутом

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string ServiceField {get; set;} // Это поле мы не хотим сериализовать/десериализовать
}

public class MyClassCollection
{
   [XmlArray("Collection"), XmlArrayItem("Item")]
   public List<MyClass> Collection {get; set;}
}
```

Затем сериализуем:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClassCollection));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, myClassCollection); // myClassCollection - наши данные
```

После чего получаем xml в виде строки из потока:

```
string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
```

И десериализуем:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MyClassCollection));
var stringReader = new StringReader(serializedData);
MyClassCollection collection = (MyClassCollection) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

Небольшие уточнения:

1. Поля для сериализация обязательно должны быть с модификатором **public**
2. Если Ваше поле имеет простой тип (например string) и Вы хотите его сделать XmlElement'ом, то расставлять атрибуты XmlElement не обязательно, поэтому иногда достаточно расставить XmlIgnore на тех свойсвтах, которые нам не нужны в сериализации/десериализации
3. XmlSerializer может иногда бросать исключение **FileNotFoundException** и это считается нормальным его поведением, так что просто игнорируйте его. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127431/xmlserializer-giving-filenotfoundexception-at-constructor) ссылка, на SO, по этому поводу.

Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Это, как раз, то, что мне нужно.

Comment: +1, но почему всё же не в settings?

Comment: Когда то задавал тут [вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/87611/c-settings-или-файл) что же лучше использовать, и согласен с ответом, поэтому и не Settings. Но это, конечно же, только мое мнение.

Comment: Я не согласен с ответом на процитированный вами вопрос. Settings лежат в строго определённом месте: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\<app name>\`, и из двух вариантов сохранения/сериализации "вручную" и автоматической я всегда предпочитаю автоматическую.

Сравните, насколько проще мой код (`Settings.Default.DataValues = DataValues; Settings.Default.Save();`) по сравнению с вашим.

Comment: В моём случае, выбор не в пользу Settings потому, что мне нужно было сохранить коллекции объектов, а не контролы, например.

Comment: @Арина:
1. В моём примере сохраняется именно коллекция объектов.
2. Контролы "сохранить" вовсе невозможно
3. В любом случае, вам решать, как вам удобнее.

Comment: @VladD, я ничего против Settings не имею - он проще. Но вариант с сериализацией более гибок и самое главное полностью в Ваших руках.

Answer (score 4):

Проще всего воспользоваться встроенным классом `Settings`. Единственная тонкость — нужен небольшой хак, чтобы поместить туда список.

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using SettingsTest.Properties;

namespace SettingsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().RunData();
        }

        List<Data> DataValues;

        void RunData()
        {
            // read
            DataValues = Settings.Default.DataValues;
            Console.WriteLine("Stored values:");
            if (DataValues != null)
            {
                foreach (var d in DataValues)
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
            }

            // modify
            Console.Write("Input int values separated by space: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            DataValues = input.Split()
                              .Select(int.Parse)
                              .Select(i => new Data()
                                           {
                                               X = i,
                                               L = new List<int>() { i - 1, i + 1 }
                                           })
                              .ToList();

            // write back
            Settings.Default.DataValues = DataValues;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Data
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public List<int> L { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Data(X = {0}, L = <{1}>)", X, string.Join(", ", L));
        }
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы поместить список в `Settings`, сделайте так:

1. Откройте свойства проекта
2. Перейдите во вкладку Settings. Если в вашем проекте ещё на добавлены Settings, добавьте их.
3. Добавьте свойство с нужным именем (`DataValues`). Вы не сможете выбрать нужный тип (`List<Data>`), поэтому выберите, например, string.
4. Зайдите в каталог проекта, и найдите там файл `Properties\Settings.settings`. Откройте его в редакторе, найдите строку `<Setting Name="DataValues"...` и поменяйте вручную значение типа на нужное: `Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;SettingsTest.Data&gt;"`. Не забывайте, что угловые скобки кодируются в XML через entity `&lt;` и `&gt;`.
5. Вернитесь в Visual Studio, обновите файлы (можно закрыть и снова открыть проект), и перекомпилируйтесь.
6. Voilà, всё должно волшебным образом заработать.

Не забудьте:

1. Дать вашему классу с данными атрибут `[Serializable]`.
2. Объявить его как `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Ответы прекрасные, плюсую оба, но ребят, девушка во первых просила удобный и быстрый способ. Но результатом вашей подсказки будет несколько классов содержащих свой сериализатор и громоздкий не масштабируемый код. Почему бы не показать сразу красивый вариант с внешним сериализатором, то биш просто вынести его в Extension, например так:

```
  public static class SerializeExtension
        {
            public static string SerializeToString(this object obj)
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);   
                return stringWriter.ToString();
            }

            public static T DeserializeString<T>(this string sourceString)
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                var stringReader = new StringReader(sourceString);
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }
        }
```

и вот код xUnit теста для проверки результата:

```
        [Fact]
        public void FirstTest()
        {
            var myClass = new MyClassCollection
                {
                    Collection = new List<MyClass>
                        {
                            new MyClass {Name = "name1", Value = "val1", ServiceField = "bla bla"},
                            new MyClass {Name = "name2", Value = "val2", ServiceField = "bla bla"},
                            new MyClass {Name = "name3", Value = "val3", ServiceField = "bla bla"},
                            new MyClass {Name = "name4", Value = "val4", ServiceField = "bla bla"}
                        }
                };

            var str = myClass.SerializeToString();
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            var res = str.DeserializeString<MyClassCollection>();
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[0].Name, "name1");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[1].Name, "name2");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[2].Name, "name3");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[3].Name, "name4");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[0].Value, "val1");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[1].Value, "val2");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[2].Value, "val3");
            Assert.Equal(res.Collection[3].Value, "val4");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [Serializable]
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Serialize();
        Deserialize();
    }

    static void Serialize()
    {
        //создаем объект который будет сериализован
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        words.Add("мир");
        words.Add("дверь");
        words.Add("мяч");

        //откроем поток для записи в файл
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.s", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        //сериализация
        bf.Serialize(fs, words);
        fs.Close();
    }

    static void Deserialize()
    {
        List<string> words;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.s", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        BinaryFormatter bf=new BinaryFormatter();
        words = (List<string>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        foreach (string w in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(w);
        }
    }

}
```

Взято [отсюда](http://code-inside.net/serialization/)

Comment: Спасибо. Я о том и думаю.
Но сложность в том, что хотелось бы сериализовать несколько листов разных классов компактно, в один файл.
Думаю идти ещё в сторону XML-сериализации.