# JSON Deserialize. Типы генерик-аргументов не могут определяться по использованию

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Переписываю с XML на JSON код ответа 2

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207217/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

```
public static class SerializeExtension
{
    public static DataContractJsonSerializer JSON_SerializeObjToDCJS(this object obj)
    {
        var ser_json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());           
        return ser_json;
    }
    public static void JSON_SerializeObjToFile(this object obj, string filename)
    {
        var ser_json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            ser_json.WriteObject(fs, obj);
        }           
    }
    public static void JSON_DeSerializer1()
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("save_json.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            JSON_DeserializeFileStream(fs);
        }
    }
    public static T JSON_DeserializeFileStream<T>(this FileStream fs)
    {
        var ser_json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var deser_json = (T)ser_json.ReadObject(fs);
        return (T)deser_json;
    }
```

На строке

```
JSON_DeserializeFileStream(fs);
```

> "SerializeExtension.JSON_DeserializeFileStream(FileStream)" не
>   могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить
>   аргументы
>   типа.

Comment: Очевидно. Откуда компилятору знать, какой должен быть тип `T`?

Comment: Вы должны знать _заранее_, какой тип вы десериализируете. Шаблонная магия это точно так же не знает.

Answer (score 1):

исправлено

```
JSON_DeSerializer<Info>("save_json.json");

public static void JSON_DeSerializer<T>(string filename)
        {           
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                JSON_DeserializeFileStream<T>(fs);
            }
        }
```

Теперь на var deser_json = (T)ser_json.ReadObject(**fs**);

> ReadTimeout = "fs.ReadTimeout" выдал исключение типа
>   "System.InvalidOperationException"
>
> WriteTimeout = "fs.WriteTimeout" выдал исключение типа
>   "System.InvalidOperationException"

```
public static T JSON_DeserializeFileStream<T>(this FileStream fs)
        {
            var ser_json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var deser_json = (T)ser_json.ReadObject(fs);
            return deser_json;
        }
```

Оказалось файл пустой.

```
var obj = Info.NewInfo();
var filename = "save_json.json";
JSON_SerializeObjToFile(obj, filename);
var result = JSON_DeSerializer<Info>("save_json.json");
```

Comment: Вряд ли вы из `FileStream`'а действительно хотите прочитать сериализованный `FileStream`.

Comment: @VladD, а можно вообще FileStream так сериализовать/десериализовать?

Comment: Внутри функции надо `T` использовать а не `Info`, иначе только его сможете десериализовывать и тогда смысл в генерике теряется

Comment: @Grundy: Что-то мне подсказывает, что нет.