# Не могу разобраться с записью и чтением XML

Tags: c#, xml

Есть документ следующего вида:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Settings>
  <section idCat="section1">
    <key1>value</key1>
    <key2>value</key2>
    <key3>value</key3>
  </section>

  <section idCat="section2">
    <key1>value</key1>
    <key2>value</key2>
    <key3>value</key3>
  </section> 
</Settings>
```

Стоит задача записывать в определенную категорию пару key-value, и также читать из определенной категории такую пару. Я запутался в бесконечных XmlDocument, XPathNavigator и прочем, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.Язык С#.

Comment: А обязательно это делать вручную? Может, использовать сериализацию в XML объекта (Пример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207217/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

Comment: Есть пара аналогичных вопросов с решениями, возможно, будет полезным: [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5894363/6935496) и [два](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16872617/6935496).

Comment: Сериализация не подходит, т.к. нужно перенести уже существующий ini файл в формат xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не хотите мучиться со всеми особенностями XML-DOM, то попробуйте использовать LiNQtoXML. Пространство имен `System.Xml.Linq`, Основной рабочий класс - `XElement`.

Загрузка исходного Xml:

```
var myDoc = XElement.Load("myFile.xml");
```

Также можно использовать статический метод `XElement.Parse(string)`, если в качестве источника используется строка.

Ищем нужный элемент:

```
var element = myDoc.Descendants("elementName").FirstOrDefault();
```

Читаем и пишем значение элемента:

```
var elValue = element?.Value;
element.Value = "newValue";//элемент должен существовать
```

Читаем и пишем атрибут:

```
var attrValue = element?.Attribute("attrName")?.Value;
element.Attribute("attrName").Value = "newAttrValue";
```

Добавим вложенный элемент c текстовым значением и атрибутом

```
element.Add(new XElement("subElement", "value", new XAttribute("attrName","AttrValue"));
```

Сохраним результат на диск

```
myDoc.Save("fileName")
```

Как видите все довольно прозрачно и понятно. XMLtoLiNQ полностью поддерживает классическую XML-DOM, но делает это изящнее чем более старый подход, реализованный в `XmlDocument` и сопутствующих классах.

Документация по ссылкам ниже содержит примеры в достаточном количестве чтобы разобраться и ссылки на описание сопутствующих классов.
[**Класс XDocument**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)
[**Класс XElement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Различные способы чтения xml, а также если неизвестно количество ключей, последний указанный способ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    [XmlRoot("Settings")]
    public class XmlRecordList
    {
        [XmlElement("section")]
        public List<XmlRecord> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlRecord
    {
        [XmlAttribute("idCat")]
        public string idCat { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("key1")]
        public string key1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("key2")]
        public string key2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("key3")]
        public string key3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeOtherClass
    {
        public string idCat { get; set; }

        public string key1 { get; set; }

        public string key2 { get; set; }

        public string key3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeOtherClass2
    {
        public string idCat { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> keys { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlRecordList result = null;

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("1.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRecordList));
                result = (XmlRecordList)ser.Deserialize(streamReader);
            }

            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter("2.xml"))
            {
                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlRecordList));
                ser.Serialize(streamWriter, result);
            }

            //или Linq
            List<SomeOtherClass> Records = (from xmlInput in XDocument.Load("1.xml").Descendants("section")
                                            select new SomeOtherClass
                                            {
                                                idCat = xmlInput.Attribute("idCat").Value,
                                                key1 = xmlInput.Element("key1").Value,
                                                key2 = xmlInput.Element("key2").Value,
                                                key3 = xmlInput.Element("key3").Value
                                            }).ToList();

            //если количество ключей неизвестно, то можно их загрузить в коллекцию следующим образом
            List<SomeOtherClass2> Settings = (from xmlInput in XDocument.Load("1.xml").Descendants("section")
                                            select new SomeOtherClass2
                                            {
                                                idCat = xmlInput.Attribute("idCat").Value,
                                                keys = xmlInput.Descendants().ToDictionary(x=>x.Name.ToString(),
                                                                                           x=>x.Value.ToString())
                                            }).ToList();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что этот вариант подходит если в каждой секции содержится только конкретное число элементов с указанными именами. Проблема в том, что в моем случае элементы указывают на определенные настройки, а потому называются по разному и категории содержат разное количество элементов.

Comment: Разное количество элементов можно загрузить, например, в Dictionary. Поправил пример.