# Архитектура приложения Windows Forms на C# (N мониторов, N форм)

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, архитектура, сериализация

Пытаюсь создать приложение на C# Windows Forms, в котором есть N мониторов и N форм.

Формы делятся на два типа:
1) Главная форма (может быть только одна);
2) Дополнительная форма (максимальное количество N-1).

При запуске приложения открывается главная форма, у которой есть кнопка "Открыть", при нажатии на которую мы можем создать дополнительную форму.

На одном мониторе может находиться только одна форма и при нажатии на кнопку "Открыть", мы должны проверять есть ли свободные мониторы. Если есть, то помещаем новую форму на свободный монитор, если таковых нет, то выводим сообщение об этом.

Цель приложения:
1) При закрытии, для всех форм: сохранить Width, Height, Location.X, Location.Y и номер монитора, на котором находится форма;
2) При открытии, выгрузка сохранённых параметров, если таковые есть;
3) Осуществлять контроль свободных и занятых мониторов.

---

Для сохранения и выгрузки я использую класс XmlSerializer, вся информация о мониторах есть в классе Screen. С главной формой всё работает, но трудности возникают со множеством форм. Как лучше всего продумать иерархию классов, чтобы все данные можно было сериализовать в один файл? Где хранить информацию (Width, Height, Location.X, Location.Y, номер монитора) о всех формах и где отслеживать события (создание, перемещение, изменение размера) связанные с ними? Может использовать паттерн MVC?

Надеюсь, получилось доходчиво объяснить суть вопроса. Заранее спасибо за советы, решения, наводки.

Comment: Количество мониторов не является постоянным и может меняться даже во время работы программы.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, но это уже следующий этап. Допустим, после сохранения параметров всех форм в XML и закрытия приложения, отключили один монитор, на котором как раз была форма и т.д. Так или иначе, для начала нужно сделать базу.

Comment: Я могу прямо во время работы изменить способ работы винды с мониторами - было 2, если включу дублирование, станет 1.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вариантов масса, но это уже после того, как сделаю основу.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что приходит в голову - создание специального класса, который будет решать задачу по управлению нужными данными для форм в том числе и их сериализацию/десереализацию.

Т.е. вероятно, вам нужна некая коллекция, в которой хранятся нужные параметры каждой формы, и реализован механизм сериализации этой коллекции в этот самый один файл.

Варианты разные технически могут быть (через массив, List или еще как), суть одна - имеем коллекцию в которой каждый элемент - есть набор данных по конкретной форме. Соответственно, должны быть методы, которые могут работать с этими данными (например, считывать значения из формы и устанавливать их форме), находить нужную форму, загружать в/из XML, обработчики событий.... Потому и напрашивается класс, так как нужен механизм по хранению самих данных, так и набор методов для работы с этими данными.

В качестве дальнейшего развития я бы дополнительно сделал класс базовой формы, где были бы прописаны (например, в обработчиках событий) нужные действия (например, отслеживание изменений размеров и положения формы). Таким образом сама форма умела бы работать с коллекцией, и при её изменении она сама бы автоматически записывала данные в "свой" элемент коллекции. Тут же можно было бы сделать механизмы валидации, т.е. проверки, а не занят ли монитор другой формой и что делать, если занят и т.д.
Естественно, тогда все остальные формы были бы унаследованы от базовой.

Либо, несколько иной вариант, это вызывать методы нашего объекта по считыванию и записи информации из коллекции только тогда, когда это необходимо (запуск и завершение программы). Но тут не решается вопрос с автоматической валидацией (проверками дополнительных условий). Т.е. если мы читаем и пишем данные руками, то и вызов проверяющих методов тоже нужно делать будет руками.

Более того, возможно, я бы создал еще и интерфейс, который объявлял бы все методы по работе с данными, это позволило бы делать разные и независимые друг от друга варианты реализации.

Comment: Начну с того, что создам приложение, которое просто открывает N форм при нажатии на кнопку с главной формы и при закрытии сериализует их в XML (размер, положение и т.д.). Сейчас архитектура такова: есть класс Form_main, главная форма с кнопкой "Открыть" и класс Form_additional, дополнительная форма. Поля данных и события находятся внутри этих классов. Плюс есть класс Settings, поля данных которого: переменная Form_main для главной формы и, как вы и предложили, коллекция List<Form_additional> для дополнительных. Класс Settings я и пытаюсь сериализовать, пока не поддаётся.

Comment: А что именно не получается? И, кстати, я бы сохранял не весь класс `Settings`, а сериализовал бы только `List<Form_additional>`. При этом с точки зрения программы и коллекции нет разницы ведь между главной формой и дополнительными. Ведь у главной формы есть ровно те же самые свойства, что и у дополнительных. 
А про сериализацию List [был вопрос с ответом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/207217/222168).

Comment: Пытаюсь сериализовать объект Settings в событии FormClosed главной формы и на строчке "XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));" программа выходит из этого события и работает дальше, форма остаётся открытой. Отличие главной от дополнительной в кнопке "Открыть", тогда в классе Settings попробую создать только одно поле данных List<Form> и туда буду добавлять все формы.

Comment: @Solution_fo List<Form> просто так сериализовать не выйдет, т.к. Form несериализуемый класс. Вложенные контролы образуют направленный граф с циклами (коллекция потомков и у каждого ссылка на родителя), такое автоматечески не сериализуется, только руками.

Comment: А и не нужно всю форму тут сериализовать, как мне кажется, просто делаем объект, в котором в полях (свойствах) перечисляем необходимые свойства формы, делаем коллекцию таких объектов, и её (коллекцию) уже сериализуем.

Comment: @rdorn, благодарю, что сообщили, я бы так долго мучился. В итоге создал 2 класса, первый - хранит информацию о форме, а второй - это коллекция объектов первого класса. Сериализую второй класс, всё работает.