# Собственные ConnectionStrings приложения для каждого пользователя операционной системы

Tags: c#, config

Как известно, в файле app.config принято хранить строки подключения. К тому же, это довольно просто.

Однако, если приложение позволяет управлять списком подключений (т.е. добавлять новое подключение, удалять существующее, редактировать существующее), изменения в строках подключения будут касаться всех пользователей операционной системы, работающих с данным приложением.

Каким образом хранить строки подключения для каждого пользователя отдельно?

Пытался сохранять в user.config. Строки подключения в таком случае сохраняются и читаются прекрасно, но если в этом файле хранится пользовательская переменная, то при следующем считывании этой переменной выпадает исключение

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Ошибочно использовать раздел,
>   зарегистрированный как allowExeDefinition='MachineToApplication' за
>   пределами приложения, в пользовательской конфигурации.  (Это поведение
>   по умолчанию, если не указано иное)

Интернет молчит как рыба. Или у меня абсолютно неправильный подход к этому вопросу?

```
//save connectionString in user.config
ConnectionStringSettings cSS = new ConnectionStringSettings(NewConnName, NewConnString, _providerName);
Configuration roaming = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = roaming.FilePath;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(cSS);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Теперь user.config выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="1" connectionString="Host=1;Port=1;Username=1;Database=1"
            providerName="Npgsql" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <userSettings>
        <QConsole.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CurrentConnectionIndex" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
        </QConsole.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Если попытаться считать переменную при следующем запуске приложения,

```
ComboBox_Connections.SelectedIndex = Properties.Settings.Default.CurrentConnectionIndex;
```

то выпадает исключение

Comment: Просто сохраните список строк в Settings: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/207616/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо за наводку. Остановился пока на бинарной сериализации в user.config.