# Добавление и сохранение массива элементов ArrayList в Settings.settings

Tags: c#, config

Необходимо сохранять в массив ArrayList элементы следующего типа:

```
MyType
{
    public string ValueS { get; set; }
    public int ValueI { get; set; }
}
```

Добавил в Settings.settings параметр MyArray, тип System.Collections.ArrayList, область Пользователь.

При добавлении экземпляров типа MyType в массив MyArray данные вроде как добавляются и массив имеет уже 1, 2 и т.д значений, но при сохранении параметров и повторном запуске программы массив снова пустой.

В самом файле конфигурации .config этот параметр (MyArray) вообще отсутствует.

В таблице настройки конфигураций, параметру ArrayList добавил значение через редактор коллекции Object - System.Object. Теперь в файле .config появилась строка следующего плана:

```
        <setting name="MyArray" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
                <ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <anyType />
                </ArrayOfAnyType>
            </value>
        </setting>
```

Я так понимаю нужно заменить anyType как-то на мой тип и в этом типе отдельно прописывать значение каждого свойства ValueS и ValueI типа MyType?

Comment: что мешает сделать свой конфиг, и классы для работы с ним?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, не хочется выдумывать что-то, когда имеются свои стандартные методы работы с конфигом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/207616/218063 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466102/218063 Но, скорее всего, нормально десериализовать ArrayList с объектами не выйдет, т.к. сериализатор не догадается что за объекты там лежат, лучше сразу брать типизированную коллекцию, вроде `List<MyType>`